# Android Keystore.getEntry NullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, keystore

My App crashes several times for several users.
But I can't repeat that situation, I can only find them in Google Play Console.

some people told me alias could be problem, because keyStore.getEntry returns NPE when alias is null,

but I put string value to alias. so it could not be null.
Please help me...

This is Crash Information

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleMakeApplication (ActivityThread.java:7189)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:7134)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600 (ActivityThread.java:274)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2102)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:496)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
at java.security.KeyStore$PrivateKeyEntry.<init> (KeyStore.java:559)
at java.security.KeyStore$PrivateKeyEntry.<init> (KeyStore.java:526)
at java.security.KeyStoreSpi.engineGetEntry (KeyStoreSpi.java:527)
at java.security.KeyStore.getEntry (KeyStore.java:1623)
at com.hpml_19102301.util.AndroidKeyStoreUtil.init$app_release (AndroidKeyStoreUtil.kt:76)
at com.hpml_19102301.application.HappApplication.onCreate (HappApplication.kt:25)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1190)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleMakeApplication (ActivityThread.java:7184)
```

This is my code.

```
private lateinit var keyEntry: KeyStore.Entry

@Suppress("ObjectPropertyName")
private var _isSupported = false

private val isSupported: Boolean
    get() = _isSupported

private lateinit var appContext: Context

internal fun init(applicationContext: Context) {
    if (isSupported) {
        Log.e("temp", "Already init twice!")
        return
    }

    this.appContext = applicationContext
    val alias = "${appContext.packageName}.rsakeypairs"
    val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSOTRE_INSTANCE_TYPE).apply {
        load(null)
    }

    var result: Boolean = if (keyStore.containsAlias(alias)) {
        true
    } else {
        // use RSA 
        if (initAndroidM(alias)) {
            true
        } else {
            initAndroidL(alias)
        }
    }

    //Specific line which throws NPE!
    this.keyEntry = keyStore.getEntry(alias, null)  //TODO: The code when throws NPE 
    _isSupported = result
}
```

Comment: make sure your build variant is pointing to release

Comment: First of all thanks for replying, Does build variant matters? I'm asking you cause I don't really know the relationship between NPE and build variant. Plz reply, thanks.

Comment: seems like no one knows the solution about it..

Comment: We seem to have exactly this problem. @MasonKim, did you manage to solve it, work it around or figure out what was going wrong?